# Pick Random, no repeat, play all once, script for my playlist

Tags: powershell

I have a setup where a dozen randomly chosen mpg's are chosen from 12 folders and then sent to a playlist to play.  What I'm trying to add is the ability to keep track or a log of the mpg when it is played and not replay it until all mpg's in a folder have been played once.  So in other words, I will be picking a random file/shuffling, and not repeating; playing all once before any one is repeated.  It should also be able to keep track of this day to day with the pc being turned off and on again.

I am currently running this script that I found.

---

```
$formats =
@("*.mpg")
$dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
gci "$dir\*" -include $formats | Get-Random -Count 1 |
Invoke-Item
```

---

I would like to add script to this .ps1 file I'm calling PlayRandom.ps1

I would like the script to create a log of each file played, and read that log before picking a new file at random.  If the file has already been chosen, then do not choose it, until all files have been played.  Then it can reset the choice of files to play.  Basically so that I can have a random, no repeat, play all once, script for my playlist.

Comment: You'd need to keep a running list (or, as you said, a log - but that's not worth disk I/O IMHO) of any file played.  If you find that your `Get-Random` returns a filename in that list, then do the `Get-Random` again until it's not in that list.  Once it's played every item, reset the list, and start over.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.  What kind of scripting would that entail?

Comment: See my sample below.  I confirmed it works as you requested.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please upvote and mark as accept.  Otherwise, please let us know if you had any further issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample.  A few notes/caveats:

1. I changed the filetype to `mp3` below, so this test code works universally on Windows machines for the most part, so change it back to `mpg` if you need it to be.
2. I specified the `$dir` explicitly as the sample music folder.  Change as you prefer.  I'm not sure why you were using `$MyInvocation` anyway.
3. There's a lot of added code in order to calculate the length of the song.  That way, it knows how long to wait (+5 seconds) before starting the next track.
4. Your default audio player's behavior is going to potentially cause different functionality.  Try Windows Media Player if you have issues, and it should work fine.  Instantiating separate copies of something like WinAmp or VLC, for example, could result in problems or memory leaks.  Turn off repeat if it's on!

---

```
$formats = @("*.mp3")
$dir = Split-Path "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\*"

$ListOfMPGs = gci "$dir\*" -include $formats

$ShuffledList = $ListOfMPGs | Sort-Object {Get-Random}
$COMShell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application

foreach ($MPG in $ShuffledList)
{
    #the below lines retrieve the song length from the file(s)
    $FolderInfo = Split-Path $MPG
    $FileInfo = Split-Path $MPG -Leaf
    $shFolder = $COMShell.NameSpace($FolderInfo)
    $shFile = $shFolder.ParseName($FileInfo)
    $MPGLength = $shFolder.GetDetailsOf($shFile, 27)
    $MPGSecondsToSleep = (([int]$MPGLength.Split(':')[0] * 60 * 60) + ([int]$MPGLength.Split(':')[1] * 60) + ([int]$MPGLength.Split(':')[2]) + 5)

    #this is where the song gets launched, and when it waits as well    
    Invoke-Item $MPG
    Write-Host ("Waiting " + $MPGSecondsToSleep)
    #the above is just so you can see how long it will wait below - omit if desired
    Start-Sleep -s $MPGSecondsToSleep
}
```